# DAX division is giving me odd values when using a measurement

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, data-analysis

I have a table "Stonks". The relevant columns in this issue are **[close]** and **[Datetime]**.

- I have a Date Filter set up, and a graph.
- I have a **What-If** parameter that gets a single value from a slider ,**[StockCountValue]**
- I have a measurement that calculates **[close]** based on filtered **[Datetime]** (the earliest date after filtering). It looks something like this:

> ```
>  BuyingPrice = 
>     VAR x = CALCULATE ( 
>             MIN ( Stonks[Date]),ALLSELECTED ())
>             RETURN 
>                  CALCULATE(SUM(Stonks[close]),FILTER(Stonks,Stonks[Date]=x))
> ```

- I have another measurement that calculates [StockCountValue] * [close]

> ```
>  Measure 2 = 
>      SUMX(Stonks,(StockCount[StockCountValue] * Stonks[close] ))
> ```

I want to divide [StockCountValue] by [BuyingPrice].

- Issue: If [StockCountValue]= 340, and I do [StockCountValue]/340, I get normal values in the graph, BUT if I replace "340" with **[BuyingPrice]** (which is equal to 340 in this context), my Graph changes dramatically (all the values become 340). I've been looking into this issue for 6 hours, can't seem to find a solution. Please help.

[image: StockCountValue / 340]

[image: StockCountValue / BuyingPrices -which has the value 340]

The final Measurement ,that returns the odd values is: Measure = SUMX(**Stonks**,(**Stonks[close]** * **StockCount[StockCountValue]**))

Comment: Please add the DAX you have been using what gives you the wrong values..

Comment: Sorry, I missed that one. I posted the final Measure :D

Comment: Looking at your image I do not believe all your values are 340. It seems you cut of your graph..